# Github Oauth with subdomain

Tags: github, oauth, oauth-2.0, github-oauth

From Github official documentation, these are the good/bad callback urls:

```
CALLBACK: http://example.com/path

GOOD: http://example.com/path
GOOD: http://example.com/path/subdir/other
BAD:  http://example.com/bar
BAD:  http://example.com/
BAD:  http://example.com:8080/path
BAD:  http://oauth.example.com:8080/path
BAD:  http://example.org
```

Does this mean that having a subdomain as a callback URL is bad ? (knowing that the homepage is also a subdomain)

I tested oauth with the domain example.com in development (configured in my /etc/hosts to use localhost) but when I deployed to production where I use a subdomain (subdomain.mydomain.com), I had this error:

```
?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fapps%2Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch&state=IDDbDeU3IyLe
```